# Not able to run Google Glass developers Samples

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm starting developing some apps on Google Glass and I've tried to run the sample project that appears on the official developers.google.com/ page [charades sample](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-charades-sample)  but when I import them on my Android Studio (Beta 0.8.6) it doesn't resolve all the imports.

```
import com.google.android.glass.media.Sounds;
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.Gesture;
import com.google.android.glass.touchpad.GestureDetector;
```

The package of the project is

```
package com.google.android.glass.sample.charades;
```

seems that they hadn't upload all the project files.
Any suggestion?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the version of Android Studio you are using in this question.

Comment: sure @MarkScheel! I already updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an importing issue: when importing the project, Android Studio assigns a wrong SDK to the module.

You need to change the SDK in build.gradle.

from

```
compileSdkVersion 21
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
```

so the build.gradle (Module: app) should look like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.android.glass.sample.charades"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it solves my problem I just had to download the Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19 after changing the compileSdkVersion on the build.gradel and works!

Answer (score 1):

Some of the official samples have not been udpated for Android Studio.  Compass has, Charades has not.

To deal with the case of an Eclipse project that you want to run in Android Studio:

Open Eclipse and import existing android project and choose the folder for the Compass project (download it from Github page).

Right click the project and select Export

Choose Android and Generate Gradle Build files

If you look in your folder you will see a new build.gradle file

Quit Eclipse to avoid ADB weirdness on some platforms and open Android Studio

File > Import Project > select the build.gradle file from above

Next, it might prompt you to update your Gradle version, do this and let it sync

Then your conifguration might need some help, if you press Play and it pops open a edit configuration dialog, tell it what activity to launch as default, in this case it is: "StartGameActivity".

Finally change the sdk version in build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19"
```

After you do this, the project will build and run on Glass.

Here is a repo of that result, please fork as you wish:

https://github.com/mscheel/gdk-charades-sample